# WPScan doesn't catch wordlist

Tags: wordpress, security, passwords, brute-force

I'm testing the security of passwords for a primary audit but the wordlist is not working on WPScan. Here is my command line:

docker run --rm wpscanteam/wpscan -u http://placeholdertargetedblog.com --wordlist ~/Desktop/wl/words.txt --username admin

here is my output:

[!] The file /Users/MBP-Will/Desktop/wl/words.txt does not exist

but when I do:

open ~/Desktop/wl/words.txt

it works.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try entering the absolute path to the file in your docker command

Answer (score 3):

You run wpscan in a docker container but you try to use a locale file outside the container. To access the password file, you have to mount the password file with -v:

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd)/words.txt:/wpscan/words.txt --rm wpscanteam/wpscan --url http://placeholdertargetedblog.com --enumerate users --wordlist words.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me having copied the extracted `rockyou.txt` into the current directory:

```
docker run -it -v --rm $(pwd)/rockyou.txt:/wpscan/rockyou.txt wpscanteam/wpscan --url http://192.168.1.105/wordpress --enumerate u --passwords rockyou.txt
```